# Mongo and Mongoose - .find() returns different values

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mern

Stumped here and it should be something extremely simple.

I have a MERN stack application that is not finding data from mongo as expected.

From the frontend I post and update the document. I log into the Mongo CLI and I can see the data that I have saved.

But with the Node application, Mongoose does not return the full document.

Here is my route to get the document -- I even try to test getting Everything.

```
router.get("/", async (req, res) => {
  const user_email = req.query.user_email;
  const course_id = req.query.course_id;
  const test = await CourseProgressSchema.find({
    _id: "60acfd1c969cac0bd3a213a8",
  });
  console.log(test);
  try {
    let course_progress;
    if (user_email && course_id) {
      course_progress = await CourseProgressSchema.findOne({
        user_email,
        course_id,
      });
      if (!course_progress) {
        const newCourseProgress = new CourseProgressSchema({
          user_email,
          course_id,
        });
        course_progress = await newCourseProgress.save();
      }
    } else if (user_email && !course_id) {
      course_progress = await CourseProgressSchema.find({ user_email });
    } else if (course_id && !user_email)
      course_progress = await CourseProgressSchema.find({ course_id });
    else {
      res.json({ error: "Not Found." });
    }
    console.log(course_progress);
    res.json({ success: course_progress });
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
    res.json({
      error: "Soemthing went wrong when getting current course progress.",
    });
  }
});
```

course_progress is consoled/returned as:

```
[0] [
[0]   {
[0]     _id: 60acfd1c969cac0bd3a213a8,
[0]     user_email: 'nickisyourfan@icloud.com',
[0]     course_id: '60acfcfe969cac0bd3a213a7',
[0]     __v: 0
[0]   }
[0] ]
```

But if I acccess the mongo cli and use `db.courseprogressscchemas.find().pretty()` It returns the updated document:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("60acfd1c969cac0bd3a213a8"),
    "user_email" : "nickisyourfan@icloud.com",
    "course_id" : "60acfcfe969cac0bd3a213a7",
    "__v" : 0,
    "course_progress" : {
        "60acfca1969cac0bd3a213a5" : {

        }
    }
}
```

Here is my Schema - nothing special:

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const CourseProgressSchema = new Schema({
  user_email: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  course_progress: {
    type: Object,
    required: true,
    default: {},
  },
  course_id: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
});

module.exports = CourseProgress = mongoose.model(
  "CourseProgressSchema",
  CourseProgressSchema
);
```

Can anyone help me to figure out why mongoose is only returning part of the document rather than the whole thing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mongoose doesn't show the **empty objects** by default. In order to get those, you have to set the `minimize` flag to `false` while creating the schema.

```
const CourseProgressSchema = new Schema(
  {
    user_email: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
    },
    course_progress: {
      type: Object,
      required: true,
      default: {},
    },
    course_id: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
    },
  },
  { minimize: false }
);
```

Comment: Will do - I am sure this was my problem thanks so much!